# A bunch of Webpack bundles or a single one?

Tags: webpack, requirejs, lazy-loading

I've got a legacy codebase with a bunch of `require()` scattered all around the project.
For example the app main module looks something like this.

```
define([
  'underscore',
  'jquery',
  //... another modules
], function(_, $) {
  exports.pay = function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      require([
        'modules/payment/PaymentModel',
        'modules/payment/PaymentView',
      ], function(PaymentModel, PaymentView) {
        PaymentView.getInstance(PaymentModel).getPaid().then(resolve, reject);
      });
    });
  };
})
```

Or even with dynamic naming in the middle of modules.

```
define([/*...*/], function(/*...*/) {
  /*...*/
    require([
      'modules/'+moduleName+'/'+moduleName+'Model',
      'modules/'+moduleName+'/'+moduleName+'Collection',
      'modules/'+moduleName+'/'+moduleName+'CollectionView'
    ], function(Model, Collection, CollectionView) {
      /*
        some code here
      */
    });
  /*...*/
});
```

As a result we have a slow project in production with up to 70-90 js files which load separately.
As you can understand there is no bundler at all.
I don't know the idea of the previous developer but I think it was something like some sort of lazy load.
The main task of mine is to speed up the project.
So I decided to take **Webpack** to incapsulate all the code into a single bundle.
But during the process I faced a many problems such a described one with dynamic loads.
Webpack creates about 30 bundles with a total size of about 900K which is 200K after gzipping.

```
$ find build/ -type f -name '*bundle.js' -exec ls -l {} \; | awk '{total = total + $5}END{print total}'
878054
```

How would you solve the problem of a slow project in this case? Would you use Webpack? If so would you strive to combine all JS files into a single bundle or leave separate bundles created by Webpack as is?

Comment: My suggestion is to ditch AMD (requireJS) module style & convert it into esm, you can do it easily with code mode, such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/amd-codemod

Comment: Switch to esm and apply lazy-load properly + code splitting.